# Django - Query to retrieve pk from other model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to create a query to grab the pk of the current post from the database. Then set it as the foreign key of the new post. I am using formview, and the model I am trying to retrieve the 'id' from is called Projects. Id is the primary key of the model Projects.

How would I be able to go about this?

pk=5 because I didn't know how to get the current one.

views.py

```
class ProjectDetailToDoForm(FormView):
    model = ProjectsToDo
    form_class = ProjectToDoForm
    success_url = '../..'

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ProjectDetailToDoForm, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self,form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.project = Projects.objects.get(pk=5)
        self.object.save()

        return super(ProjectDetailToDoForm, self).form_valid(form)

class ProjectDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Projects
    context_object_name = 'indprojects'
    template_name = 'projectpage.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProjectDetail, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['todolist'] = ProjectsToDo.objects.order_by('project_tododate')
        context['todoform'] = ProjectToDoForm()
        context['form'] = ProjectForm(instance=Projects.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug']))
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Projects.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ProjectDetail, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

models.py

```
class Projects(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    project_title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    project_shortdesc = models.CharField(max_length=248)
    project_desc = models.TextField()

    def save(self):
        super(Projects, self).save()
        date = datetime.date.today()
        self.slug = '%i%i%i%s' % (
            date.year, date.month, date.day, slugify(self.project_title)
        )
        super(Projects, self).save()


class ProjectsToDo(models.Model):
    project_tododate = models.DateField()
    project_tododesc = models.TextField(max_length = 500)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Projects)

    def __unicode__(self):
            return '%s %s' % (self.project_tododesc, self.project_tododate)
```

Comment: Use singular names for model classes.

Comment: What defines the "current" project though? Where so you want to get that information from?

Comment: Each project page can be defined by a slug, and each project has its own unique ID. These are stored in the model: Projects

Comment: Your view looks like it should subclass from ``UpdateView`` or ``CreateView`` rather than ``FormView``.

Comment: But how do you decide which project is active? Your code does not tell us.

Comment: Oops sorry, I added more to my views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that you define the active project using the url. In that case, you can do something like this:

urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<project_slug>[\w-]+)/add_todo/$', 
    views.ProjectDetailToDoForm.as_view(),
    name='add_todo',
),
...
```

view

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    project = Project.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs["project_slug"])
    self.object.project = project
    self.object.save()

    return super(ProjectDetailToDoForm, self).form_valid(form)
```